# Mood Ring Effect Material

Tags: materials

I have searched many different terms and phrases to try to learn a way to create the effect of the thermotropic liquid crystal paint (kind of like a mood ring) which is similar to a heat map. I can't seem to find much about it. It doesn't seem like that's a question here, either. Does anyone know how I could:

1. Make a procedural material of this effect?
2. Make only certain areas show the heat map like effect and leave the rest a dark color, if that's possible? (Similar to how it looks when you touch only a part of a surface painted with thermotropic liquid crystals.) I assume I would mask it out, but how?

I'm using Blender 2.92 on Windows 10.

Comment: can you please share an example of the effect you are trying to achieve? it seems pretty easy with a color ramp, but  an example could help to help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an idea of how to get that temperature ramp effect with nodes:

here's the final effect:

[image]

here's the node setup: as you see it's just a textures connected with a color-ramp node (I also added a noise texture to make it a little bit more random and some math nodes to balance the final values to match the color-ramp that need a range of 0 to 1 range input)

[image]

here's the blend file if anyone want it
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Sanbaldo! This is the effect I wanted to create! I mostly understand the material setup, but if you would, could you explain a couple things? I just want to understand the following:
1) Why did you add the subtract node to the noise node? And why a value of 0.3?
2) The math nodes that come from the image texture: Why did you use an Add and then Subtract node? And how did you know what values to set them to?

I'm still a little new to this, so I just want to make sure I get it so I can use this idea in the future for other materials. Thank you for your time!

Comment: if you want to get the right values of the math node, you just need to experiment.
The ColorRamp gets as input a value between 0 (white) and 1 (black). So if you add some noise to the texture, you'll shift the input values and so it would be useful to fix it using a math node (substract) to shift the values back to a good range.

Please note that you can avoid using "add" and "substract" nodes and you can just play with the ColorRamp node.

Comment: Okay, that makes the concept more clear for me.